# Как агрегировать значения из таблицы

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть исходная таблица в `word`. Стоит задача перенести логику в `sqlite`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого я создал 4 таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Визуально они выглядят вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос. Как составить запрос чтобы Прилагательные (`partsOfSpeech`) для каждого слова (`word`) попали в одну строку (как на первом рисунке)

Вот мой запрос. Осталось понять как прилагательные собрать в одну строку

```
SELECT 
  word.name, 
  partsOfSpeech.name, 
  examples.name
FROM (examples INNER JOIN word ON examples.id = word.id) INNER JOIN    
(partsOfSpeech INNER JOIN combinations ON partsOfSpeech.id = combinations.word_id) 
ON word.id = combinations.ps_id;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ps ссылка на саму бд 
https://yadi.sk/d/f7VANwWFroiwlQ

Comment: Я же вроде в предыдущем вопросе приводил пример как это сделать?

Comment: @AlexR. я не доконца расписал там задачу, думал удалить задание и снова раписать тут - но сайту это не понравилось.

Comment: Второй запрос как раз и собирал все прилагательные в одну строчку

Comment: К структуре есть вопросы. Один пример может распространяться на несколько слов, сейчас у вас не так. `partsOfSpeech` - вроде как части слова, но по примеру опять же теже слова, тогда это таблица не нужна, а в `combinations` сделать две ссылки на `word`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  word.name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(partsOfSpeech.name, '; ') partsOfSpeeches, 
  examples.name
FROM (examples INNER JOIN word ON examples.id = word.id) 
INNER JOIN (partsOfSpeech INNER JOIN combinations ON partsOfSpeech.id = combinations.word_id) ON word.id = combinations.ps_id
group by word.name, examples.name
```

Чтобы не группировать по большим строкам можно это сделать подзапросом, если они поддерживаются SQLLite

Comment: подскажите плиз по вопросу - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136664/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: не хватает знаний подкорректировать ваш запрос