# Как убрать дубли из агреггированной таблицы

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть 4 таблицы. Word и Adj связанны отношением многие ко многие через таблицу Combinations. Examples связано отношением многие-к-одному  Word
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит задача получить значения для каждого слова (Word) в таком виде

```
people|young,other,live,new...|любой пример из examples
person|.....|любой пример из examples
```

У меня запрос выдает некорреткные данные

```
select
  w.name word,
  GROUP_CONCAT(adj.name,',') adjectives,
  e.name
from combinations c,
     "adjectives" adj,
     word w,
     examples e

where c.word_id = w.id
and   c.adj_id = adj.id 
and e.word_id = w.id
group by w.name
ORDER by w.id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему то дубли в колонке идут

https://yadi.sk/d/f7VANwWFroiwlQ бд sqlite

полная структура

```
CREATE TABLE adjectives (
    id   INTEGER NOT NULL
                 PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT    NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE combinations (
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL
                    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                    UNIQUE,
    word_id INTEGER NOT NULL
                    REFERENCES word (Id),
    adj_id  INTEGER NOT NULL
                    REFERENCES adjectives (id) 
);
CREATE TABLE examples (
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL
                    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name    INTEGER,
    word_id INTEGER REFERENCES word (Id) 
);
CREATE TABLE word (
    Id   INTEGER NOT NULL
                 PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
);
```

Comment: Получи сперва DISTINCT список слов в подзапросе, и только потом собирай с помощью GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: а примерчик можно плиз?)

Comment: Замените файл дампа на CREATE TABLE таблиц + тестовые данные в формате INSERT INTO + эталонный ответ для этих тестовых данных. Всё - отформатированным текстом.

Comment: Ок, 33% выполнено. Осталось "тестовые данные в формате INSERT INTO" (достаточно по 2-3 записи на связь) и "эталонный ответ для этих тестовых данных".

Comment: По структуре лучше сделать по аналогии связки `word`, `adjectives`, `combination`: `word`, `text`, `example` (связь слов с текстом). Один текст может быть примером многих слов.

Comment: @AlexR.эмм.. непонимаю о чем речь

Comment: А точно запрос работает? Поле `e.name` не входит в группировку. В sqlite так можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если требуется любая запись из таблицы `example`, то можно использовать подзапрос с ограничением

```
select
  w.name word,
  GROUP_CONCAT(adj.name,',') adjectives,
  (select e.name from examples e where e.word_id = w.id limit 1) name
from combinations c,
     adjectives adj,
     word w
where c.word_id = w.id
and   c.adj_id = adj.id 
group by w.name, w.id
ORDER by w.id
```

Думаю после этого и дубли уйдут.

Comment: как у вас это получается)

Comment: спасибо @Alex//